# Issues with PHP and MYSQL Not Updating Database

Tags: php, mysql, session

I have spent a few hours trying to debug this to no-avail. If someone could tell me how to fix this without actually giving me the code. (I like to learn). That would be amazing.

Form Section:

```
        <form method="POST" action="./updatelink.php">
                                <label for="link" style="color: #678098; font-size: 17pt;font-family: roboto;">Your Steam Trade URL: </label>
                                <input type="text" name="link" class="form-control trade-url-input" style="" id="link" value="<?php echo fetchinfo("tlink","users","steamid",$_SESSION["steamid"]); ?>" placeholder="Link exchange">
                                <p>Fetch your Steam URL: 
                                <a href="http://steamcommunity.com/id/me/tradeoffers/privacy#trade_offer_access_url" target="_blank" style="color: #678098; font-size: 12pt;font-family: roboto;">http://steamcommunity.com/id/me/tradeoffers/privacy</a>
                                </p>
                                <p style="color: #FF3F3F; font-size: 12pt;font-family: roboto;">Make sure your Steam URL is Valid!</p>
                                <p style="color: #FF3F3F; font-size: 12pt;font-family: roboto;">Entering an invalid URL would prevent you from getting your winnings!</p>
                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" value="Save">
                             </form>
```

UpdateLink File

```
    <?php
@include_once('set.php');
@include_once('steamauth/steamauth.php');
if(!isset($_SESSION["steamid"])) {
    Header("Location: index.php");
    exit;
}
$link = $_POST["link"];
$link = mysqli_real_escape_string($link);
$steam = $_SESSION["steamid"];
if($result = mysqli_query( "UPDATE `users` SET `tlink`='$link' WHERE `steamid`='$steam'"))
{
    printf($result);
}
Header("Location: settings.php");
exit;
?>
```

Comment: `value="<?php echo fetchinfo("tlink","users","steamid",$_SESSION["steamid"]); ?>"` You sure the double quotes with the php tag aren't screwing it up for you there? Just looking at the syntax highlighting implies it. Or the "fetchinfo"?

Comment: Yeah Tried with and without :/

Comment: What exactly are you trying to send with that form?

Comment: if($result = mysqli_query( "UPDATE `users` SET `tlink`='$link' WHERE `steamid`='$steam'"))
{

Answer (score 2):

Two things here:

1. `mysqli_real_escape_string()`
2. `mysqli_query()`.

Both of those functions require a database connection be passed as the first parameter.

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Plus, your connection requires it to be `mysqli_` and not any other API than its own.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php

Also make sure the session was started inside all files using sessions.

- http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php

Check for errors:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Plus, seeing those spaces before your opening `<?php` tag;  make sure you're not outputting before header.

Then you have an `href="#"` in:

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" value="Save">
```

- It needs to be removed.

---

To verify that the UPDATE truly was successful, use `mysqli_affected_rows()`.

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php